# can we store method passing argument in java variable

Tags: java

how can i store this displayPriceMessage method with argumetnt  in variable

```
//method of displayPriceMethod
 public void displayPriceMessage(String name, String msg, boolean cream, boolean coke)
{
        priceamoutntxt.setText("\n Name: "+Ename.getText().toString()+"\n total : "+priceamoutntxt.getText()+"\n Add Ice-Cream ?"+ cream +"\n Add Coca-Cola ?"+coke+"\n than you ");
}

//  displayPriceMessage argumetnt
displayPriceMessage("ename","",isIceCream, cocaCola);
```

Comment: You can use functional approach: create `Runnable r = () -> method`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in FP. Perhaps you would need a custom Functional Interface.

```
DisplayPriceMessage displayPriceMessage =  this::displayPriceMessage;

public void displayPriceMessage(String name, String msg, boolean cream, boolean coke)
{
    priceamoutntxt.setText("\n Name: "+Ename.getText().toString()+"\n total : "+priceamoutntxt.getText()+"\n Add Ice-Cream ?"+ cream +"\n Add Coca-Cola ?"+coke+"\n than you ");
}
```

Create a functional interface having an abstract method of similar signature as that of displayPriceMessage

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface DisplayPriceMessage {
    void displayPriceMessage(String name, String msg, boolean cream, boolean coke);
}
```